# Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token in script

Tags: javascript, codeigniter

```
var abc = "<?php $this->db->where('tv_schedule_status', 'Active'); $this->db->where('tv_schedule_source', 'facebook'); $this->db->order_by('tv_schedule_date', 'asc'); echo $result = $this->db->get('tv_schedule')->row()->tv_schedule_date_time; ?>";
```

---

Comment: what does this line of code look like in the browser?

Comment: you cant assign PHP query to javascript.

Answer (score -2):

Have u try to remove your `"<?php`
and the closure `?>"` dont forget the last semicolon too...
try this..`<?php
echo '<script> var abc = "$this->db->where('tv_schedule_status', 'Active'); $this->db->where('tv_schedule_source', 'facebook'); $this->db->order_by('tv_schedule_date', 'asc'); echo $result = $this->db->get('tv_schedule')->row()->tv_schedule_date_time; "; </script>' ?>`

Comment: what happen if remove php then??

Comment: Ask something in the comment box not as an answer

Comment: @Devsi: As u say, we cant assign php inside var..@Danish: sorry, newb here...